# Half-elf dilettante using implement powers

Tags: dnd-4e

Can a half-elf from a class that does not use any implements use his dilettante racial trait to choose an at-will power with the implement keyword? At higher levels, would that allow him to use an implement with a magical bonus, or is he stuck at using that power with no enhancement bonus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Half Elf Dilettante does *not* grant any implement proficiency. You can still use the power (unless a specific implement is required). But, no, you can't use enhancement bonuses from magic implements at higher levels either.

However, most implement powers can be used with *any* implement, and thus if you are part of an implement wielding class already, you do not *generally* need a special implement for your dilettante power.

Comment: Okay, but then why do many of the Multiclass feats state that you can use Class implements for Class powers? And there's a feat in Arcane Power that lets you gain another Arcane Implement; why have these feats if you can pick and choose Implements?

Comment: @WashingtonPearce some implements *are* class specific for the purposes of feats and some powers (for instance "warlock implements" "sorcerer implements" are used) This means that the source of the implement proficiency must come from that class (or in the case of arcane implements, a class of that power source). However to *use* an implement with a specific power type, you don't need proficiency from any specific class (unless otherwise specified).

Comment: Worth noting that there's an Implement Proficiency feat (Arcane Power). You have to have an Arcane class to take it, but that could potentially be a multiclass.

Comment: @WashingtonPearce the original rules actually did require you to wield certain types of weapons- see PHB 3, for example, which says "the implement must be a type wielded by the power's class or paragon path." (PHB3 219)  That was officially changed later on (I know it no longer exists in the RC; I'm not sure if it changed earlier).